# Creating NSTimeZone object

Tags: swift, foundation, nstimezone

When would `NSTimeZone(name:"US/Eastern")` return `nil` ?

I am seeing multiple crashes, with stacktrace pointing to the line of code where I initialize NSTimeZone. I can add a check to see if its nil. But curious to know why is it returning nil for just some users.

I tried changing device localization, change time zone, Airplane mode. Unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you asking when it will be `nil` specifically for the name `"US/Eastern"` or for any possible name used?

Comment: Because there's no timezone with the identifier you specified. `NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames` will give you all available timezones that Foundation recognizes. Use `America/New_York` or any other American city in the same eastern timezone.

Comment: @CodeDifferent: `NSTimeZone(name:)` can succeed even for names not listed in `NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames`, that happens with `"US/Eastern"` in my test.

Comment: @rmaddy Asking why this could be nil ? In what cases can initializer fail.

Comment: @0x8badf00d The documentation clearly states when it will be `nil`. If you pass an unknown time zone id.

Answer (score 0):

First, use TimeZone, not NSTimeZone (in Swift 3). Second, this initializer is failable, so you have only yourself to blame if you are crashing. Your job is to *check* whether the result was `nil`, not *assume* that it wasn't.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I did add a check for nil after I found the crash. I should have paid attention to documentation that initializer can return nil. But I'm curious to know when does this fail.